# Laravel builder get value

Tags: laravel

How I can take event_id column value?

[image]

Thanks

**Change**
I'm using laravel-admin and I have to show header with event name, but when the event do not have participant get error:

```
 Trying to get property 'event' of non-object (View: /usr/home/gernikaracing/Apps/timing/vendor/encore/laravel-admin/resources/views/grid/table.blade.php)
```

Code

```
protected function grid()
    {
        $grid = new Grid(new Participant);

        $eventId = request()->route('event');
        $grid->model()
                ->where('event_id', $eventId)
                ->orderBy('number', 'asc');

        $grid->header(function ($query) {
            $event = $query->first()->event->name;
            return "<div style='background-color:#f7f7f7; font-size: 18px; text-align: center; padding: 7px 10px; margin-top: 0;'>$event</div>";
        });
        $grid->authorized(__('Authorized'))->editable()->sortable();
        $grid->number(__('Number'))->sortable();
        $grid->driver()->full_name(__('Driver'))->sortable();
        $grid->admin_user()->name(__('Author'))->sortable();
        $grid->updated_at(__('Updated at'))->sortable();

        $grid->disableCreateButton();
        $grid->disableFilter();
        $grid->disableActions();
        $grid->disableExport();
        $grid->disableRowSelector();

        return $grid;
    }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should show your code...

Comment: Edited the post

Answer (score 0):

$builder->get()->first()->event_id;

Comment: Thanks, you. It's the first thing I did before writing here, but if do not include any participant give the error above (post updated)

Comment: It is preferred that you include some explanation along with your code.

Comment: Then your first() method is returning null for whatever reasons. Try `dd($query->toSql())` to see what sql is being generated.